# CGI in C: Page Redirect

Tags: c, http, cgi, http-redirect

I have a piece of C CGI code that executes on an account registration page. I am trying to find out how to have the page automatically redirect to the home page after the CGI executes. I searched online but could not find anything clear in regards to C.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP has [`Location`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header for redirection. You could send the following buffer to redirect client to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location
```

or

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Location: /local/redirect/
```

for local redirection. HTTP clients following the standards would send GET request to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location` or your `/local/redirect/` page after receiving any of the above header accordingly.

Comment: For NPH style scripts, the script can generate its own status line. But, for plain CGI scripts, the presence of the `Location` header should cause the server to generate the `302`.

Answer (score 1):

The following example code will redirect whatever request to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com).
The response should follow the cgi protocol specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.3.2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcgiapp.h>

int main() {
  FCGX_Stream *in, *out, *err;
  FCGX_ParamArray envp;
  while (FCGX_Accept(&in, &out, &err, &envp) >= 0) {
    FCGX_FPrintF(out, "Location: https://www.youtube.com\r\n\r\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```